# Any Better Alternative to Using Conditional Count Statements in Terraform?

Tags: count, terraform, conditional-statements, resources

I am interested to see if anyone knows of any better alternative to using conditional count statements in Terraform. By "conditional count statement", I mean a statement where depending a condition like a variable input, count will evaluate to create either 0 or 1 of a resource.

A simple example:

```
resource "xxxxxxxx" "example" {
count = var.example != null ? 1 : 0
}
```

Here, the resource will only be created if var.example has a value (is not null), otherwise it will not get created.

Conditional counts usually work ok in practice, but sometimes in more complex uses than the one above it introduces a risk of getting an error during Terraform Plan where it cannot evaluate the result of the count pre-apply.

```
The "count" value depends on resource attributes that cannot be determined
until apply, so Terraform cannot predict how many instances will be created.
To work around this, use the -target argument to first apply only the
resources that the count depends on.
```

Is there any better way to achieve the same effect of creating resources on a conditional basis in Terraform?

Comment: Well, the error you posted is not the same as the example: variables are fine but if you want to use the attribute/argument of a resource that is about to be created that will not work. Also, you could use `for_each` instead of `count`.

Answer (score 6):

It varies by case, but there are some cases where you need to get around this. There is a clever trick, but it seems obtuse in the single item (binary exists or not) case. But in a case where there are actually multiple items, this should help.

This is a completely contrived example but I actually use the method quite a bit. In short, a list of things not known until apply, can be replaced by a list of objects with a key you don't care about. The purpose is that `for_each` doesn't mind if the value is unknown at plan-time, only if the key is.

Consider the following root module with these four modules.

#### main.tf

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "this" {
  bucket = "h4s-test-bucket"
}

# module "with_count" { # cannot be determined until apply
#   source = "./with-count"
#   x = aws_s3_bucket.this.id
# }

module "with_for_each_over_item" { # handy workaround
  source = "./with-for-each-over-item"
  x      = aws_s3_bucket.this.id
}

output "with_for_each_over_item" {
  value = module.with_for_each_over_item
}

# module "with_for_each_list" { # cannot be determined until apply
#   source = "./with-for-each-list"
#   x      = [aws_s3_bucket.this.id]
# }

module "with_for_each_list_better" { # handy workaround
  source = "./with-for-each-list-better"
  x      = [{ y = aws_s3_bucket.this.id }]
}

output "with_for_each_list_better" {
  value = module.with_for_each_list_better
}

module "with_for_each_list_best" { # handier workaround
  source = "./with-for-each-list-best"
  x      = [aws_s3_bucket.this.id]
}

output "with_for_each_list_best" {
  value = module.with_for_each_list_best
}
```

#### with-count/main.tf (problematic)

```
variable "x" {
  type    = string
  default = null
}

resource "null_resource" "this" {
  count = var.x != null ? 1 : 0
}

output "this" {
  value = null_resource.this
}
```

#### with-for-each-over-item/main.tf (handy workaround)

```
variable "x" {
  type    = string
  default = null
}

resource "null_resource" "this" {
  for_each = { for i, v in [var.x] : i => v }
}

output "this" {
  value = null_resource.this
}
```

#### with-for-each-list/main.tf (problematic)

```
variable "x" {
  type    = list(string)
  default = []
}

resource "null_resource" "this" {
  for_each = toset(var.x)
}

output "this" {
  value = null_resource.this
}
```

#### with-for-each-list-better/main.tf (handy workaround)

```
variable "x" {
  type    = list(object({ y = string }))
  default = []
}

resource "null_resource" "this" {
  for_each = { for i, v in var.x : i => v }
}

output "this" {
  value = null_resource.this
}
```

#### with-for-each-list-best/main.tf (handiest workaround)

```
variable "x" {
  type    = list(string)
  default = []
}

resource "null_resource" "this" {
  for_each = { for i, v in var.x : i => v }
}

output "this" {
  value = null_resource.this
}
```

### Summary

In cases where the variable has a value not known at plan-time, consider using an object where the key is known.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping in mind that your terraform config not shown I've used a general example of `for_each` instead of `count`.

This is an example of how 2 CNAME records will be created using & in this example terraform modules are used but the same can be done directly on terraform resources.

```
locals {
    cname_records = {
        "email" = ["email.domain.net."]
        "imap" = ["imap.domain.net."]
        }
}

module "aws_route53_record_CNAME" {
    source = "app.terraform.io/terraform-cloud-org/route53-record/aws"
    version = "1.0.0"
    for_each = local.cname_records
    records = each.value
    name = each.key
    zone_id = "YOUR-HOSTED-ZONE-ID"
    type = "CNAME"
    ttl = "300"
}
```

Comment: With the above example with for_each, would there be the same ability to create zero resources depending on input? So like if cname_records contained nothing, would for_each be able to handle the null value and thus not create any resource?

Comment: Yes, it would be no problem @EmMa.